# Wordpress blogcontent not in class

Tags: wordpress, blogs

Currently working a html -> wordpress theme and having struggles with blogcontent.
I made a page-blogpost template and a single-blogpost template.

The problem is the following:

In my single-blogpost template I wrote the code:

```
<p class="blogpost-text"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
```

Which, I thought should normally put all of the blogpost content INSIDE the "blogpost-text"-class. However this is what happens when I view the code in the browser:

```
<p class="blogpost-text"></p> -> EMPTY ?
<p>Lorem ipsum... </p> -> (this is the blogpost content text1)
<p></p> -> Enter inside the blogpost content
<p>Lorem ipsum... </p> -> (this is the blogpost content text2)
```

Comment: Maybe try using div? p tags aren't usually meant to be nested inside each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no special requirement for p tag then use other html tag.

```
<div class="blogpost-text"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:

```
<p class="blogpost-text"><?php echo get_the_content(); ?></p>
```

I have tested it. Its works fine.